# Multiple Python Distributions -- Managing Packages

Tags: python

Ubuntu (10.10) came installed with Python2.6, 2.7, and 3. In addition, I have installed the Enthought Python Distribution. Is there any way to manage Python packages within these distributions intelligently?

For compatibility, I'd imagine switching between these distributions occasionally. If I install *PyBlah*, I'd like it to be available under all of the distributions. Can I do better than installing *PyBlah* under each distribution?

Comment: I think linux uses /usr/share for this. There is /usr/share/pyshare and /usr/lib/pyshare. I think the behavior is package-specific, but when I install packages from Enthought, they get put in one of the share folders and a symlink gets made from python2.6.

Answer (score 4):

Well you can't install a package across 2.x-3.x distributions, they're not compatable. So the easiest ( and recommended way) is to install it for each version.

If you're sure you want to install it for all your versions, you can install it somewhere like `~/lib/python/` and add that directory to your `PYTHONPATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper make managing packages very nice!